# How to Deflate + encode the SAML request in JMEter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am creating a JMeter script which is Microsoft AD enabled. While launching the application i am getting SAML request in response header. The same value is passed in below request as different format(deflate + encoded base64)

Ex : Transaction 1 response :
'`saml2?SAMLRequest=lZLLbtswEEV%2FReCeoiS%2FCduAG%2FdhwLWN2OmiG4OkKIcoRaqcYdv8fWi5RdNFA2RHDOfcmXsxcxCt7fgq4qO719%2BjBsx%2BtdYB7z8WJAbHvQAD3IlWA0fFj6vPW17lBe%2BCR6%2B8JS%2BQ1wkBoAMa70i2WS%2FIfvd%2Bu%2F%2B42Z2Lejip68GYikkh6HBSKjqbNA0d1GMhpWrksFEk%2B6IDJHZBklQSAIh64wCFw1QqqpKWJa2qUzHi1YgXxVeSrZMf4wT21CNiB5wx6y%2FG5a1RwYNv0DtrnM6Vb9lI1o2sBkloNprSYaUKOhUzSQtVi3I6nhQDWbGry4pkh9%2Fm3xlXG3d53be8NQH%2FdDod6GF%2FPJFs9SeLO%2B8gtjocdfhhlH643%2F7dVUm0eS1QdFZg40ObA15yG1vwNl5hyJ1Gdu5sTKbYNyOFE%2BzsO50GAgbPzqBVDAaf%2BsWZUECW8%2BuT9wGG5dtGzdlLdn47n10yvFkfvDXqKfuQUIH%2Fz6PMy75iatr0rTw66LQyjdF1isVa%2F%2FMuaIF6QTBETTK2vE39906Xzw%3D%3D`'

Same value converted in Transaction 2 request:

```
saml2?SAMLRequest=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
```

I have tried the base64 encoded option but i am getting below error

```
{"strHeaderText":"Sign in","unsafe_strTopMessage":"Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.","strMainMessage":"We received a bad request.","strAdditionalMessage":"","strServiceExceptionMessage":"AADSTS750056: SAML message was not properly base64-encoded.","strTraceId":"36919936-0681-450d-b9a1-6c8a45372d00"
```

May i know how to handle this issue in JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting an [URL-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) value and sending the decoded one, just feed the encoded value to JMeter's [__urldecode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urldecode) and that will be it.

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. it's working fine now